# Is there a scikit-learn conditional logistic regression module

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there a conditional logistic regression module within scikit-learn?
If so, how can it be used?
It is not clear from the user manual whether this aspect is covered.

Comment: Could you be more explicit by providing a definition? If you want to condition to e.g. strata of your data, you may be able to augment the labels with this information and work with ratios of probabilities output by `predict_proba`, but it may not be exact. Another possibility would be to restrict yourself to exactly what you are conditioning on. In any case, the official answer to your question is "no".

Comment: @eickenberg, could you give some more detail about how you were thinking to implement this? Or what else you needed to know to give an answer? I am also thinking about implementing this.

Comment: Well, there would be need of a reference defining the procedure exactly. Especially in the context of scikit-learn, how would the procedure fit into the API? If you just want to use scikit-learn logistic regression for this, you should check whether you can build the required loglikelihood by restricting the training data to the appropriate strata - just a matter of comparing formulas.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for it - it is not available in scikit-learn yet, but you can find an implementation of [conditional logistic regression in statsmodel](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.conditional_models.ConditionalLogit.html).